# Need to restrict a character "." to be entered in validation text box in dojo

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I need to restrict a character from the validation text box in dojo; i.e. when the user enter's an "."(dot) into validation text box of dojo, The dot should not appear in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

In your html :

```
<div id="tb"></div>
```

In your JS :

```
require(["dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
     "dojo/on",
     "dojo/_base/event",
    "dojo/domReady!"], 
function(ValidationTextBox, on, event){
    var textBox = new ValidationTextBox({}, "tb");
    on(textBox.domNode, "keypress", function(evt){
        var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
        if ("." === String.fromCharCode(charOrCode)) {
            event.stop(evt);
        }
    });
});
```

Declarative example :

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox">
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="keypress" data-dojo-args="evt">
        require(["dojo/_base/event"], function(event){
            var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
            if ("." === String.fromCharCode(charOrCode)) {
                event.stop(evt);
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. Actually i am using declarative way of coding in dojo. I tried the below way it worked is it a right way, or is there any other way to write declarative code.Added a onKeyPress event in html and also i see "stopEvent" deprecated. Could you please help me in this?                                                      function ValidationDotCheck(evt){
        var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
        if ("." === String.fromCharCode(charOrCode)) {
            dojo.stopEvent(evt);
        }
  }

Comment: Just replace dojo.stopEvent by event.stop and you will no longer have deprecations. Don't forget to require dojo/_base/event as this is what "event" is aliased to, as in my example.